# Moving drawn shape using mouse listener

Tags: java, mouseevent, graphics2d, mouselistener

working on a simple Paint java project, its required to draw shapes for example(line , circle , rectangle ,........)
I am trying to write methods where I can move , delete and resize a selected shape.
My code should be right as I already test it at another project that has one drawn rectangle.
my paintComponent method to select shapes and add them to ArrayList

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;


        for (ShapeItem item :shapes) {
            if (!(item.getShape() instanceof Line2D)){
                g2d.setColor(item.getColor());
                g2d.fill(item.getShape());
            }
            else {
//              g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
                g2d.setColor(item.getColor());
                g2d.draw(item.getShape());
            }

        }

        if (selectedShape != null){
              g2d.setStroke ( new BasicStroke(1f, 
                       BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, 
                       BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 
                       1f, 
                       new float[] {2f}, 
                       0f) );
              if (selectedShape.getShape() instanceof Ellipse2D) {
                  Rectangle rect =  selectedShape.getShape().getBounds();

                  g2d.draw(rect);
              }

              else if (selectedShape.getShape() instanceof Rectangle2D) {
                  Rectangle2D dotted = new Rectangle2D.Double((int)((Rectangle2D) selectedShape.getShape()).getX() - 6, 
                                    (int)((Rectangle2D) selectedShape.getShape()).getY() - 6, 
                                    (int)((Rectangle2D) selectedShape.getShape()).getWidth() + 12, 
                                    (int)((Rectangle2D) selectedShape.getShape()).getHeight() + 12);  
                  g2d.draw(dotted);
              }

              else if (selectedShape.getShape() instanceof Line2D) {
                  Rectangle rect =  selectedShape.getShape().getBounds();

                  g2d.draw(rect); 
              }

              else if (selectedShape.getShape() instanceof Polygon) {
                  Rectangle rect =  selectedShape.getShape().getBounds();

                  g2d.draw(rect); 
              }
        }        
    }
```

Class to move shapes

```
package draw;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
//import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
//import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
//import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
//import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class DynamicShapes extends JComponent{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    MoveShapes move = new MoveShapes();
    public DynamicShapes(){
        addMouseListener(move);
        addMouseMotionListener(move);
    }

    class MoveShapes extends MouseAdapter{
        private int x;
        private int y;
        boolean pressed;
        boolean dragged;
        DrawingPanel d = new DrawingPanel();
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            super.mousePressed(e);
             pressed = false;
            for (ShapeItem s : d.getShapes()){
                if(s.getShape().contains(e.getX() , e.getY()) ){
                    pressed = true;
                    System.out.println("shape is pressed");
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            super.mouseDragged(e);

            if(pressed){

                int dx = e.getX()-x;
                int dy = e.getY()-y;
                for (ShapeItem s : d.getShapes()){
                    Rectangle rect = s.getShape().getBounds();
                    if(s.getShape().getBounds2D().contains(x, y)){
                        rect.x += dx;
                        rect.y += dy;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    x += dx;
                    y += dy;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

if any one can help, I don't have a big understanding of the hole graphics and mouse events as it's my first time :)

Comment: What is the problem? You say your code should work right, so why are you asking a question here?

Comment: the code of moving should be valid, but it doesn't work on the hole project :)

Comment: What exactly does not work or which effects are you able to observe?

Comment: when I select a shape and try to move it, it doesn't move.

Comment: I have no idea if it is from the code , or there is something missing

Comment: Does the shape recognize the normal click?

Comment: yes, it makes a dotted rectangle around the shape when it is clicked(selected)